# append new data to json file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have bellow json array in a data.json file

```
[{"type": "Even", "id": 1}, {"type": "Odd", "id": 2}, {"type": "Even", "id": 3}]
```

and i was trying to append new data to this json file using this code

```
    def foo(filename, dict_data):
    with open(filename, 'r') as json_data: 
        data = json.load(json_data)

    data.append(dict_data)

    with open(filename, 'w') as json_data: 
        json.dump(data, json_data)

    foo('data.json', lst)
```

but I'm getting this result

```
[{"id": 1, "type": "Even"}, {"id": 2, "type": "Odd"}, {"id": 3, "type": "Even"}, [{"id": 4, "type": "Even new"}, {"id": 5, "type": "Odd new"}`]]
```

but this is an invalid json data.
**my expected data is**

```
    [{"id": 1, "type": "Even"}, {"id": 2, "type": "Odd"}, {"id": 3, "type": "Even"}, {"id": 4, "type": "Even new"}, {"id": 5, "type": "Odd new"}`]
```

what am i doing wrong.?

Comment: I think you just need to replace the `data.append(dict_data)` with `data.extend(dict_data)`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your variable `dict_data` doesn't contain a single `dict`, but a `list` of `dict`s. You're `.append`ing that `list` inside the outer `list`, thus generating a nested structure

If that is the case, then just use `.extend` to extend the original `list` with another `list`:

```
data.extend(dict_data)
```

Consider changing the name of the variable `dict_data` to something more meaningful, because it is confusing to read your code since it doesn't even hold a `dict`.